# overflow hidden, border radius and transform in android browser

Tags: android, css, overflow, transform

I have a "box" that "cuts" a piece of a "circle", which is to say there's a div that has overflow hidden with a much large div inside of it, the inner having a border-radius.

I have another div inside that circle div that is a rectangle, which animates a rotation.

```
<div id="clipper">
    <div id="round">
        <div id="meter"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB6rf/3/), which shows the css problem (the animation is done with JS requestAnimationFrame, but that part works fine and it's a bit verbose to show here.) This happens using native Android 4.0.4 browser: so far, it works fine everywhere else CSS3 is supported.

Any magic CSS property I can use to fix this? I've tried setting background, z-index and various 3d transform properties on the `#clipper` div per other similar questions, to no avail. Oddly, it appears as though the overflow is respected on the left edge of the element only.

**Edit - Partial Fix**

Adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
-o-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

to the `#round` div fixes the overflow from the `#clipper` div, however `#meter` still overflows. Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB6rf/11/). The meter already has a transform on it.

**More information**

I've tried another layout I just thought up, which does the same thing, but fixes the issue here (doesn't fix the bug, just avoids it). However, it has created a new, even more fun Android 4.0.4 issue:

[div rotates but div's clipping box does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665031/android-4-0-4-clipping-box-does-not-rotate-with-element)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the CSS Vendor prefixes in my example, but if you add the ones you need back this might fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/FB6rf/24/

unfortunately I don't have an android device to test on, but I've updated the CSS the sanest way I could think about it. (You'll also notice the edges of the square aren't as jagged -- this problem was due to having the most inner element set to `overflow:hidden`)

Hope it helps!